# Can you omit the preposition "in" in the next sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

https://www.today.com/health/covid-heart-attack-young-people-rcna69903

This sentence reads "as he'd seen something similar other college athletes"

For me, this sounds weird as it sounds incomplete.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot omit the word "in" there; the sentence is incorrect. This is probably a typo.

Comment: Thank you! Since this is from a native English-speaker-source, it seemed really odd!